# String to Bytes Converts to Incorrect Value

Tags: solidity, string, bytes, hex

I have a string array stored in memory as

`https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmSXDsFeNaPa3CJKmn8WKBnA421Zv5r3Ra8n71LZhvEi9s`

This should convert to `68747470733a2f2f636c6f7564666c6172652d697066732e636f6d2f697066732f516d5358447346654e61506133434a4b6d6e38574b426e413432315a763572335261386e37314c5a687645693973`

As can be seen here https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter.

Instead though I'm see `4f68747470733a2f2f636c6f7564666c6172652d697066732e636f6d2f697066732f516d5358447346654e61506133434a4b6d6e38574b426e413432315a763572335261386e37314c5a6876456939`

->

`Ohttps://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmSXDsFeNaPa3CJKmn8WKBnA421Zv5r3Ra8n71LZhvEi9`

Only difference is in the first set of hex, it ends with `73` as where the second set begins with `4f`.

Using

```
    function string_tobytes(string memory s) public pure returns (bytes memory){
        bytes memory b3 = bytes(s);
        return b3;
    }
```

Any help on how to handle this would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I was converting from cpp serialized `std::string` message which contains a LEB128 encoded length prefix, thus needed to add back for deserialization:

```
// "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED"
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract strings {
    
    function string_tobytes(string memory s) public pure returns (bytes memory){
        bytes memory message = abi.encodePacked(
            uint8(bytes(s).length),
            bytes(s)
        );
        return message;
    }
}
```